# React clear state onClick

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to clear my state after onClick has been fired. However, my state doesn't update, and instead renders the initial state.

Here is the code

```js
import React from 'react';
import {firebaseCon} from '../connection';

class Update extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
   title: ""
        };

        this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({
            title: props.item.title
        });
    }

    updateItem(itemId) {
        let inputVal = document.getElementById("editData").value;
        firebaseCon.content.update('text', itemId, { title: inputVal })
        .then(() => console.log('Updating the entry succeeded'))
        .catch((e) => console.error(e));
        this.setState({ title: "" });
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        var value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ title: value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input-field col s12">
                <i className="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                <input type="text" id="editData" value={this.state.title || ""} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={this.updateItem.bind(this, this.props.item.id)}>UPDATE</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Update
```

I have a button in another component, that sets the props when clicked and my inputfield then use this as value. When changing the value, the state updates, which is working fine. However, when I then click my update button, the data is correctly updated, but the state is not updated.

Comment: what actions are performed inside the `firebaseCon.content.update` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting setState in the then block. The then block could be getting called and then never reaching setState because of asynchrony.

Try putting setState in the then block like this:

```
then(() => {
  console.log('Updating the entry succeeded');
  this.setState({title: ""}); // <--- goes inside the then block, so it gets executed 

}).catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

Comment: That actually worked. The old value blinks and then the field is cleared hehe :P

Comment: Awesome. If it helped, please checkmark the answer :D

Comment: Yea, I just can't help thinking if there is a better solution. This works, but the old value still blinks shortly, which I find very weird.

Comment: Well, I gave you a solution. So I would think this answer deserves to be selected since no one else gave an answer.